Simplifying an inverse Laplace transform
I am reading a paper, in which the author claimed that the inverse Laplace transform
$$
L_1(\rho) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\epsilon-i\infty}^{\epsilon+i\infty} e^{s\rho}
\frac{\sin{2s\alpha_1} - s \sin{2\alpha_1}}{2s\left( \cos{2s\alpha_1} - \cos{2\alpha_1} \right)} ds, 
$$
can be reduced to
$$
L_1(\rho) = \frac{\pi}{4\alpha_1^2} \int_\rho^\infty 
\frac{\sinh \rho_1}{\cosh(\pi\rho_1/\alpha_1) - 1} d\rho_1. 
$$
Here the first integral is along the path $\operatorname{Re}s = \epsilon$, $0<\epsilon<1$.
The attempt was to take the derivative and show that
$$
L_1'(\rho) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\epsilon-i\infty}^{\epsilon+i\infty} e^{s\rho}
\frac{\sin{2s\alpha_1} - s \sin{2\alpha_1}}{2\left( \cos{2s\alpha_1} - \cos{2\alpha_1} \right)} ds
$$
can be reduced to
$$
L_1'(\rho) = -\frac{\pi}{4\alpha_1^2} 
\frac{\sinh \rho_1}{\cosh(\pi\rho_1/\alpha_1) - 1}. 
$$
The integrand in $L_1'(\rho)$ does not have a pole at $s=1$, and it might be hopeful to change to another integral contour. I don't know how to proceed from here and any help is appreciated.
